# Flutter: Image Package Crop to Circle

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I am using the `Image` package to handle and process images in a flutter app. In this case, I am downloading the users profile pic and attempting to resize it and crop it to a circle. However, it does not appear to be cropping the image at all. Am I missing something here?

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ui;

    final getProfile = await http.get(Uri.parse(profilePicPath));
    final profileFile = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/image.png');
    await profileFile.create(recursive: true);
    await profileFile.writeAsBytes(getProfile.bodyBytes);
    ui.Image profileImage = ui.decodeImage(profileFile.readAsBytesSync());
    ui.copyCropCircle(profileImage, radius: 10);
```

Edit: I need to keep the image as a file and will not be shown in the UI (eventually used to overlay in another image file).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this issue, it was only a slight modification that got it to work. This pulls in the photo, stores it, resizes it, and then crops it to a cricle.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ui;

final getProfile = await http.get(Uri.parse(profilePicPath));
    final profileFile = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/image.png');
    await profileFile.create(recursive: true);
    await profileFile.writeAsBytes(getProfile.bodyBytes);
    ui.Image profileImage = ui.decodeImage(profileFile.readAsBytesSync());
    profileImage = ui.copyResize(profileImage, height: 100, width: 100);
    profileImage = ui.copyCropCircle(profileImage, radius: 50);
```